# Help with identifying a serif font with slanted e

Tags: fonts, font-identification, serif

[image]

So I'm designing an Odia font based on old letterpress types from early 1900s. Matching Latin isnt exactly necessary but would be nice to have. Those old books used a variety of Latin types but I believe this one is keeping well with the classic looks. Another requirement is font should ideally be OFL licensed so I can incorporate it in my font. I have tried several of the identifier sites, but most of them barely match.

Comment: It looks a bit like [Hightower](https://fonts.adobe.com/fonts/hightower) to me, but I think you've made this question unanswerable by requiring a free font. Anyway, if you're designing your own font, what exactly do you need this for?

Comment: I could design matching Latin but the thing is my target audience don't strictly need it and it'll be nice to have but not essential. There's also the case that the Odia books back then used several different Latin fonts, so there's no issue of being 100% faithful to this one. OFL font because my font will have the same license.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tilted 'e' suggests this is one of several types from the late nineteenth/early twentieth century influenced by the roman type of Nicolas Jenson in Venice. That was quite a large group, some were lighter in style, some more robust.

Bruce Rogers' Centaur is a typeface in this genre which has an open-source digitization called [Museum](https://www.levien.com/type/myfonts/museum.html). It's a lot lighter than this sample which has a pretty dark type color, but it's my closest recommendation. If you responded more to the overall look you might consider [Cardo](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Cardo).

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea there was such a good font based on Centaur, it is indeed a bit light but there's no need to be entirely faithful to the original. Cardo has a bit sharp angle unlike my example. Horley old style or Revival 555 fit pretty well but have no OFL alternatives. So it'll either Museum or another one I found, Wollstonecraft Romance (will have to slant its 'e' myself but it fits well otherwise)